# Edit android manifest file with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am trying to edit android manifest file with xmlstarlet. I want to change package attribute node.

Input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.demoapp">
 </manifest>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prod.demoapp">
 </manifest>
```

I tried few things, I think it's a issue with namespace. I am unable to select package attribute since it's value package name(e.g. com.test.demoapp) is a variable.

```
    xmlstarlet edit -N N="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" \
    --update "//N:manifest[@name='package']/@value" \
    --value "com.prod.demoapp" $androidManifestXMLfile
```

I also tried without namespace

```
    xmlstarlet edit \
    --update "//manifest[@name='package']/@value" \
    --value "test" $androidManifestXMLfile
```

But in both cases nothing is changed. Output is content of xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection of a `manifest` tag with attribute `name='package'` does not match anything.

Instead just select the `package` attribute itself like this:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
--update "//manifest/@package" \
--value "com.prod.demoapp" $androidManifestXMLfile
```